# 404 error during Wordpress installation using xampp (linux)

Tags: linux, wordpress, xampp

I get a 404 error when trying to access localhost/wordpress on a browser. I watched many tutorials and resources online and it's not working. My distro is linux mint.

Can anyone help? I'd appreciate it a lot.

Thanks!

I unpacked the installation file in htdocs in lampp folder of xampp.

The servers are all running. Localhost displays xampp. I created an empty database in localhost/phpmyadmin called wordpress. I changed the wp-config-samle.php to wp-config.php.  Changed the database name, username, and added two extra define lines shown below. But still not working. What can I do? Why is it not working? Does anyone know? Thanks in advance.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/wordpress');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/wordpress');
```

Comment: Did you run the installation? If you haven't written any code so far, this does not look related to programming to me